# Store spark dataframe name as variable

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I wanted to print statment which is used in function, for example :

```
def some_function(df1,df2):
    new_df = df1.union(df2)
    print (f'dataframe {df1} merged with {df2}')
```

As of now, this prints complete data frame when that data frame is called.

desired output:

```
some_function(product_data1,product_data2)
```

result output::

```
 'dataframe product_data1 merged with product_data2'
```

How to store dataframe name as variable in spark ?
in python it is done as

```
dataframe_name = df.name
```

Comment: add a `return new_df` in the function and use the function as `merged_df = somefunction(df1, df2)`

Comment: wait, what do you mean by "store dataframe name as variable"? `df.name` will result in the `name` column in `df` dataframe, right?

Comment: I want to have data frame stored as variable, which I can print. Lets say i have 5 data frames and I want to those 5 data frame names.  how can I do that? 
currently, spark gives data frame schema . 

 DataFrame[product_id: string, product_name: string, dept_name: string, class_name: string, subcat1_name: string] 

instead I just want data frame name, which is , 
'product_1'

Comment: why do you want to print a variable that you just defined? e.g., `df1 = spark.createDataFrame()` where `df1` is the dataframe name.

Comment: @samkart I believe he is asking if `DataFrame` has an attribute to store the dataframe name so that he can call it by using `df.name`

Comment: @Jonathan yes, I can use it printing statements, to show which data set was used in function as above example explains.

whole idea to simply print the dataframe name , not the dataframe schema or dataframe. Just the dataframe name.

Comment: @samkart I think in his case, `df` is just the variable name, but I think he is asking if `DataFrame` has instance attribute so that he can call the `df.name`, just like when we create the instance of a class, we can pass the arguments where `__init__` accept.

Comment: @samkart
Below links is reference to spark name function which returns  dataframe name but its not happening. 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.name.html

Comment: @JhaAyush that's an RDD method, not dataframe - did you try it on your dataframe? I'd suggest you update the question to make it clear of the dataframe name requirement. from the comments, it is clear that you want the print() in your some_function to print the dataframe names that you input in the function. not very clear in your question though.

Comment: @JhaAyush Unfortunately I think origin pyspark dataframe doesn't have such attribute to achieve your goal. I think you can create your own class and inherit `DataFrame` class OR create a dictionary to store the mapping between the name and dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, I believe the requirement is to make the `print()` within the `some_function` print the dataframe names provided to the function. While you can't print dataframe names, you can tweak the function to accept the dataframe names as strings. Following is an example.

```
def some_function(df1, df2):
    assert (type(df1) == str) and (type(df2) == str), 'Provide the dataframe names in string only - e.g., "df1"'

    new_df = eval(f'{df1}.union({df2})')  # eval() will evaluate the strings as objects
    print (f'dataframe {df1} merged with {df2}')

    return new_df

# union_df is the new appended dataframe
union_sdf = some_function('data1_sdf', 'data2_sdf')  # passed as strings
# dataframe data1_sdf merged with data2_sdf
```

Let's say someone passed actual variables (not strings) in the function. The function will raise an error.

```
union_sdf = some_function(data1_sdf, data2_sdf)  # not strings
# AssertionError: Provide the dataframe names in string only - e.g., "df1"
```

Comment: Thanks this works, but also makes query complex in nature. I think I will add option to pass string for data frame name in function. good help!